# How generate comment text using shortcut keyboard in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I want generate comments text like this below when using shortcut keyboard in Visual Studio Community

//Arrange

//Act

//Assert

Comment: You mean by using CTRL + K + C ?

Comment: Have a look at snippets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2022